# NAS as storage save against encryption virus?

Tags: encryption, nas, virus

I want to buy a NAS storage so that I can RAID the HDD's to prevent lost data if a HDD fails and use it as long term storage that I can access anytime.

The only non user error way to lose my data I can think of would be an encryption virus (Ignoring something like a fire, lightning, a thief or similar).

Since I also want to have write access to the NAS and use it inside the windows explorer, is it possible to password protect the write access as long I want to write to it and deauth myself after that so I can't write to it anymore?

Would that keep the data save for an attack like that? Or what is the way to go for something like that?

Comment: There are many ways to protect your data from ransomware attacks. I suggest looking into 'immutable snapshots' as a great way to protect your data from such attacks. Dont see your NAS/RAID as a replacement for good backups btw.

Comment: @Silbee If I am reading this right. Thats something exactly for ransomware attacks like I am searching. Do you know if it would be possible to, for example, setup a NAS with 4TB HDD Storage but only expose 2TB or 3TB and setup the NAS that the other space is used to store the immutable snapshots? So in my logic a ransomware could only access the 2/3TB portion and destroy the files while the other space with the snapshots stays untouched so I can just roll back the data? Would this considered to be safe (If it's even possible) or should the snapshots be on a differend external storage device?

Comment: [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/) has [ransomware protections](https://www.truenas.com/blog/level-up-your-ransomware-protection-with-truenas/) built into the OS that can be put in place _(same can likely be configured for TrueNAS Core [BSD-based], whereas this talks about TrueNAS SCALE [Linux-based])_ and [Controlled Folder Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/enable-controlled-folders) should be used on Windows for any directories storing non-OS data. You'll get more for your money by building your own hardware NAS and using TrueNAS as the OS

Comment: "You'll get more for your money by building your own hardware NAS and using TrueNAS as the OS". I already have a rpi 4 laying around. Would that be suitible for something like that? If it's just buing a case and power supply and get more for the money I would be down for that. Is there an tutorial or similar that explains what is needed for making my own?

Comment: @sirzento You wouldnt even have to create such a seperation, with immutable snapshots you just 'freeze' a set of data in place and any changes after that are stored outside of your snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I also want to have write access to the NAS and use it inside the windows explorer, is it possible to password protect the write access as long I want to write to it and deauth myself after that so I can't write to it anymore?

While that’s certainly technologically possible, I think this is a very weak and unreliable defense. Depending on how you do it, cached credentials could linger. And then even if you made it so they don’t, you could simply forget to log out or the malware could strike while you are logged in anyway.

Instead, you should take measures *inside* the storage server:

- Create regular filesystem snapshots. These snapshots must not be removable from outside.
- Have *offline* backups (physically disconnected).
- Have other backups (cloud or whatever) anyway, because RAID is not backup. RAID is *only* for availability (and sometimes also to avoid data corruption).

Comment: I know it's a risk but it's way better than nothing. Currently I just have a single HDD inside my computer where I store all my important data and since the HDD is pretty old by now I am scared that it will fail sometimes soon. To prevent data lose if an HDD fails I want to RAID them. And to not have them inside my pc with 100% access from my computer I want to just have a NAS where I need to auth myself before I can write to it. So with that setup I first need to be infected first and need to be authed to the NAS before the virus shows himself to get money.

Comment: I don't really want to make more efford. I would see me connect an external HDD to the NAS and make an backup once a month or so but I would prever to have maximum security without doing something by hand myself. I guess thats not really secure but having a RAID NAS with auth is way better than a single HDD inside my computer

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to use NAS as backup is to put additional effort in the process. The workflow can be something like:

1. Activate on NAS ftp server
2. work on your files
3. Once per week/day/month create zip archive of your files. Set the filename of zip to include some increasing numbers or timestamp
4. Upload the zip file with dedicated ftp client (like filezilla for example) by hand. Not via explorer access to ftp URL!!!

You will have history of files and the ftp storage will not be accessible directly from the OS for malware can't see it and encrypt the files.

P.S. Also consider uploading zip file in cloud storage to have it available offsite

Comment: As I understand this, the files I work with and the zip file are on the same NAS since on 2. I work on the files on the NAS and 4. says I upload the zip via ftp to the NAS?

Comment: @sirzento, no, files you work are on local disks. zips are on nas

Comment: @sirzento, or files to be located on specific share on NAS and you ftp upload on different share, not available for write

Comment: @sirzento, the general idea is to separate the shares (SMB/NFS/...) where your working files are located and the place where your backups are located.

Answer (score 0):

Most nas, such as the synology NAS has the option to encrypt the drive. While the drive is encrypted, the data is not accessible until you login to the NAS and decrypt the drive.

This is an anti-theft measure to ensure that if someone takes the NAS, the data is still safe.

NAS Encryption will keep the NAS files in the encrypted state until you login and decrypt the drive. It then remains decrypted until you reboot the NAS or turn it off. Well, technically speaking, the NAS is still encrypted, but if you access a file, it will decrypt on-demand as if there was no encryption enabled.

Working with just a NAS is in no way a protection against encryption viruses. These viruses, as long as they have access to the files the same way as you have, they can make changes.

A RAID mirror setup will copy the content of one drive to the other at the time of write, and is only meant to ensure that there is no data loss if one of the drives fails.

In order to have a proper protection against encryption viruses, you need a second storage location, for example a 2nd NAS, preferably also outside of your building so you are also protected in case of a fire etc, and periodically backup the entire NAS to the other NAS. Most NASses have a NAS to NAS backup solution build in.

If your main NAS becomes encrypted, you can first eliminate the virus, then restore the NAS from the other NAS.

We apply this strategy for many of our customers who don't want a full fledged server situation.

Some NASses also allow you to sync to a cloud service. Do note that this is not a good alternative in most cases because a crypto virus, when it hits, will also cause the NAS to sync the encrypted versions to your cloud storage immediately. Only if you can backup to the cloud service, rather than sync to it, then it is a viable way.

Comment: "These viruses, as long as they have access to the files the same way as you have, they can make changes." So If I would encrypt the drives inside the NAS. Would a virus only be able to change files while I am logged in or would it still have access to the encrypted files and just destroy them so I can't decrypt them anymore?

Comment: If you use NAS encryption, you only protect the files from theft, not from viruses. As you decrypt the NAS to access the files yourself, at that same time Viruses can access the files and thus modify them, too. A NAS will remain decrypted until it is rebooted or powered off.